# Parker Solar Probe and clock correction

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, parker-solar-probe, clock

Due to the dynamic changes in speed and the value of the gravitational field in which the Parker Solar Probe stays, the clocks should have the errors due to relativistic effects.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348854/parker-solar-probe-passing-extremely-close-to-the-sun-what-relativistic-effects

Did the breakdown of clocks turned out to be in line with the expectations of the relativistic theory?

Sorry for My English.

Comment: It's a good question. Since it's really about the operation of equipment aboard a spacecraft, I think it might be better suited in Space SE than here in Astronomy. Clocks in computers on spacecraft are reset regularly, the same way that clocks in computers and cell phones are reset regularly. Every time we connect to the internet our computers's clocks are checked against "internet time" and if the difference is large enough, we get a reset. Deep space spacecraft have regular connections with Earth and their clocks are managed as well.

Comment: But before they do that they most likely do read the clock first, and so ground control does have an opportunity to look for shifts due to GR effects. Have a look at the comments, and the answers under [Parker Solar Probe passing extremely close to the Sun; what relativistic effects will it experience and how large will they be?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/348854/83380)

Comment: Certainly an experiment regularly checking the difference between the spacecraft clock and "Earth time" to look for the expected GR effects could be considered an Astronomical observation and thus **on topic here**, and since these effects will be by far the largest for for any spacecraft to date (flying closest to the Sun) it will be of interest. But if no answers appear here within a week or two I'd recommend asking a moderator to migrate to Space Exploration SE where folks are more likely to have access to specific information that can answer this.